# Compute outer product of arrays with arbitrary dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, slice

I have two arrays `A,B` and want to take the outer product on their last dimension,
e.g.
`result[:,i,j]=A[:,i]*B[:,j]` 
when `A,B` are 2-dimensional.

How can I do this if I don't know whether they will be 2 or 3 dimensional?

In my specific problem `A,B` are slices out of a bigger 3-dimensional array `Z`,
Sometimes this may be called with integer indices `A=Z[:,1,:], B=Z[:,2,:]` and other times
with slices `A=Z[:,1:3,:],B=Z[:,4:6,:]`. 
Since scipy "squeezes" singleton dimensions, I won't know what dimensions my inputs 
will be.

The array-outer-product I'm trying to define should satisfy

```
array_outer_product( Y[a,b,:], Z[i,j,:] ) == scipy.outer( Y[a,b,:], Z[i,j,:] )
array_outer_product( Y[a:a+N,b,:], Z[i:i+N,j,:])[n,:,:] == scipy.outer( Y[a+n,b,:], Z[i+n,j,:] ) 
array_outer_product( Y[a:a+N,b:b+M,:], Z[i:i+N, j:j+M,:] )[n,m,:,:]==scipy.outer( Y[a+n,b+m,:] , Z[i+n,j+m,:] )
```

for any rank-3 arrays `Y,Z` and integers `a,b,...i,j,k...n,N,...`

The kind of problem I'm dealing with involves a 2-D spatial grid, with a vector-valued function at each grid point.  I want to be able to calculate the covariance matrix (outer product) of these vectors, over regions defined by slices in the first two axes.

Comment: Can you post some example input and output?

Comment: Have you looked at numpy.multiply.outer? I think this is what it does (but I haven't read this post that closely).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discovering the use of ellipsis in numpy/scipy arrays 
I ended up implementing it as a recursive function:

```
def array_outer_product(A, B, result=None):
    ''' Compute the outer-product in the final two dimensions of the given arrays.
    If the result array is provided, the results are written into it.
    '''
    assert(A.shape[:-1] == B.shape[:-1])
    if result is None:
        result=scipy.zeros(A.shape+B.shape[-1:], dtype=A.dtype)
    if A.ndim==1:
        result[:,:]=scipy.outer(A, B)
    else:
        for idx in xrange(A.shape[0]):
            array_outer_product(A[idx,...], B[idx,...], result[idx,...])
    return result
```

Answer (score 3):

You may have some luck with einsum :

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html

Comment: I did not know about this function. Looks very useful. Thanks.

Comment: I'd try this if I were using numpy >1.6.0 (I'm not)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've understood you correctly, I encountered a similar issue in my research a couple weeks ago. I realized that the Kronecker product is simply an outer product which preserves dimensionality. Thus, you could do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

# Generate some data
a = np.random.random((3,2,4))
b = np.random.random((2,5))

# Now compute the Kronecker delta function
c = np.kron(a,b)

# Check the shape
np.prod(c.shape) == np.prod(a.shape)*np.prod(b.shape)
```

I'm not sure what shape you want at the end, but you could use array slicing in combination with `np.rollaxis`, `np.reshape`, `np.ravel` (etc.) to shuffle things around as you wish. I guess the downside of this is that it does some extra calculations. This may or may not matter, depending on your limitations.